# how to do a 'project > clean' in command prompt for a Java maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, batch-file, jenkins

I have a maven project which I am running on Jenkins. Project contains config.properties file in resources folder under the project root directory. Sometimes when I compile & run the project, I get an error: `Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: property file 'config.properties' not found in the classpath`

With eclipse, when I do a 'Project > Clean', I get rid of this error. However, since I am running this in Jenkins using a batch file, I cant 'Project > Clean'. As a dirty workaround, I open the project in eclipse, do a 'Project > Clean' and re-build the project on Jenkins, which works fine thereafter.

How can I 'Project > Clean' when running it from a batch file in Jenkins?

**Update:**
This is how my project structure looks like. config.properties file holds my environment details on which the tests are executed.

[image]

**POM.xml:**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>100</forkCount>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <!--other repositories if any -->
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.local</groupId>
        <artifactId>ewsc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.local</groupId>
        <artifactId>msgparser</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: You should not need to clean the project to begin with, and somehow rely on Eclipse somewhere during the build. Can you post more about your current config? Your POM? What is `config.properties`? How is it being used?

Comment: @Tunaki - Have answered your questions and have added details. Hope that info suffices.

Comment: You should really consider moving your Jenkins-Files out of your projects source-code. That might be what's causing the strange behavior you're describing ... Also, config.properties should be located under /src/test/resources if only needed for Tests, not /resources

Comment: @tom - thanks, moving the config.properties file to /src/test/resources worked. Could you elaborate, how this made the difference? How does JRE pick up the file from /src/test/resources and why in what case should I use /resources? Maybe you could write it as an answer and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config-File is located under a Folder `/resources`

That folder isn't picked up by Maven (or the m2e Eclipse Plugin) by default, as `/resources` isn't part of the default Maven Directory structure.
By default ressources should be placed under `src/test/resources` if they are only needed for testing.

For a List of directories that are considered by Maven out of the box see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html:

There is a Maven Build Helper Plugins you can use to extend the considered Folders http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html, however, if you haven't got a good reason to go down that road I'd suggest sticking with the Default Directory Structure.

Answer (score -1):

`mvn clean *target*` in command line should do the trick.

"If for some reason, adding clean to the command-line is not an option, the Clean Plugin can be put into a project's pom.xml so that it gets executed every time the project is built."

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>auto-clean</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Source: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/usage.html

Comment: `mvn clean` and Eclipse's "Project > Clean" option are _completely_ different.

Comment: Apparently, I see the error "Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: property file 'config.properties' not found in the classpath" consistently after doing a mvn > clean and project > clean fixes it.